# Refresh DFP ads

Tags: refresh, ads, double-click

I have a static chat page with Google DFP ads around it.

Is there a way to get those ads automaticly refresh every 5 minutes or so?
I just want to refresh the ads, not the whole page.

I know that Google offers some tags like googletag.pubads().refresh(); but im not sure if i can use them for this purpose.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check here it is feirly simple:
https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/2694377?hl=en&ref_topic=28788

Comment: Provide context for links.
Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah just set an interval of 300000 and use the refresh method like you mentioned. Technically I think it may be against the terms of service to refresh the ads on a timer without user interaction... but I'm not 100% on that and you would need to research the terms a bit more on the DFP site.

Answer (score 0):

This code should help:

```
<html>
<head>
  ...
</head>
<body>
  ...
      <!-- PUT THESE LINES ON THE FOOT OF YOUR PAGE -->
<script type="text/javascript">
   setInterval(function(){googletag.pubads().refresh();}, 300000);});  
</script>
```