# Refresh ads in Google DFP

Tags: google-dfp

Having DFP refresh issues when following the directions on their site.

I've tried the other method seen here: [Refresh DFP ads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279851/refresh-dfp-ads) without any luck.

Have a plugin that we created to stick ad units into widgets and it works fine. Trying to update it to refresh ads and it will not refresh anything. When I try to add the button to refresh ads manually to test it makes the ads disappear completely.

Here is the code that's in the head:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var googletag = googletag || {};
    googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
    (function() {
    var gads = document.createElement('script');
    gads.async = true;
    gads.type = 'text/javascript';
    var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
    gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
      '//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
    var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
    })();
    </script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    googletag.defineSlot('/5251611/db_archive_leaderboard_728x90_1', [728, 90], 'div-gpt-ad-1436890018007-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.defineSlot('/5251611/db_frontpage_leaderboard_728x90_1', [728, 90], 'div-gpt-ad-1436890018007-1').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.defineSlot('/5251611/db_frontpage_leaderboard_728x90_2', [728, 90], 'div-gpt-ad-1436890018007-2').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.defineSlot('/5251611/db_frontpage_med_rect_300x250_1', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1436890018007-3').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.defineSlot('/5251611/db_frontpage_med_rect_300x250_2', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1436890018007-4').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.defineSlot('/5251611/db_frontpage_med_rect_300x250_3', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1436890018007-5').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.defineSlot('/5251611/db_frontpage_med_rect_300x250_4', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1436890018007-6').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.defineSlot('/5251611/db_frontpage_med_rect_300x250_5', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1436890018007-7').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.defineSlot('/5251611/db_frontpage_med_rect_300x250_6', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1436890018007-8').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.defineSlot('/5251611/db_frontpage_pencil_975x50', [975, 50], 'div-gpt-ad-1436890018007-9').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.defineSlot('/5251611/db_half_page_300x600', [300, 600], 'div-gpt-ad-1436890018007-10').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.defineSlot('/5251611/db_posts_leaderboard_728x90_1', [728, 90], 'div-gpt-ad-1436890018007-11').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
    googletag.enableServices();
  });
</script>
```

And this is a sample of the ad plugin code :

```
 <!-- /5251611/db_half_page_300x600 -->
    <div id='div-gpt-ad-1436890018007-10' style='height:600px; width:300px; padding:10px 0px 10px 10px;'>
 <script type="text/javascript">  
        googletag.cmd.push(function() {
        var slot10 = googletag.defineSlot("/5251611/db_half_page_300x600", [300, 600],
        "div-gpt-ad-1436890018007-10").addService(googletag.pubads());
        googletag.enableServices();
        googletag.display("div-gpt-ad-1436890018007-10");
    setInterval(function(){googletag.pubads().refresh([slot10]);}, 30000);       
        });
      </script> 
</div>
```

The ad code above is the same for 10 ad slots with the slot number changed in each one. What am I missing here? Cannot get it to refresh after 30 seconds.

Comment: Console is telling me "Uncaught ReferenceError: slot10 is not defined"

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError was due to repeating the 'setInterval(function(){googletag.pubads().refresh([slot10]);}, 30000);' line in the end of the body, The google instructions on how to implement refresh aren't very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Console is right. setInterval function does not recognize slot10 because it out of its scope. If you were to just write the following: googletag.pubads().refresh([slot10]) rather than using it in setInterval function then you will see that the ad will be refreshed.

You should make your code so that setInterval can actually access slot10. Maybe you should pass slot10 as a variable for your setInterval function??